# jwplayer for audio not working in firefox throw this error log "No suitable players found and fallback enabled"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jwplayer

i am use jwplayer in my webso "http://bajao.biscoot.com/" but it is not work with firefox
please help me

My Javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").removeClass("pause_song").addClass("play_song");
    jwplayer().onReady(function(){
        volumeControl(jwplayer().getVolume());
        vol = jwplayer().getVolume();
        if(jwplayer().getVolume() == 0){
            $(".volume_button").addClass("mute");
        }

        playerReady = 1;
    });
    jwplayer().onBufferChange(function(){
        //playerReady = 1;
        });

    jwplayer().onPlay(function(){
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").addClass("pause_song");
    });

    jwplayer().onPause(function(){
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").removeClass("pause_song").addClass("play_song");
    });
    jwplayer().onBuffer(function(){
        $(".play_song").addClass("buffering");
    });
    jwplayer().onIdle(function(){
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering");
    });
    jwplayer().onPlaylistComplete(function(){
        repeatNorepeatList();
    });
    jwplayer().onTime(function(event){
        if(plyFlg == 1){
            $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").removeClass("pause_song").addClass("play_song");
            jwplayer().pause();
            plyFlgFun();
        }else if(parseInt(vldtFlg) < parseInt(cdate) || parseInt(vldtFlg) == 1){
            $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").removeClass("pause_song").addClass("play_song");
            jwplayer().pause();
            vldtFlgFun("stream");
        }else{
            if(parseInt(onloadPlay) == 0){
                if(parseInt($(".scrub > div").height()) == 0){
                    mis(cIdR, dataR, 1);
                }else{
                    mis(cIdR, dataR, 0);
                }
                onloadPlay = 1;
            }
        }

        setmediaTime(event.position,event.duration);
    });

    jwplayer().onBeforePlay(function(){
        //setMediaData();
        });
    jwplayer().onError(function(e){
        //alert(e.message);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least have an inital jwplayer().setup() on the page first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jwplayer().onReady(function(){
        volumeControl(jwplayer().getVolume());
        vol = jwplayer().getVolume();
        if(jwplayer().getVolume() == 0){
            $(".volume_button").addClass("mute");
        }
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").removeClass("pause_song").addClass("play_song");
        playerReady = 1;
    });
    jwplayer().onBufferChange(function(){
        //playerReady = 1;
    });
    jwplayer().onPlay(function(){
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").addClass("pause_song");
    });
    jwplayer().onPause(function(){
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering").removeClass("pause_song").addClass("play_song");
    });
    jwplayer().onBuffer(function(){
        $(".play_song").addClass("buffering");
    });
    jwplayer().onIdle(function(){
        $(".play_song").removeClass("buffering");
    });
    jwplayer().onPlaylistComplete(function(){
        repeatNorepeatList();
    });
    jwplayer().onTime(function(event){
        setmediaTime(event.position,event.duration);
    });

    jwplayer().onBeforePlay(function(){
        //setMediaData();
    });
    jwplayer().onError(function(e){
        //alert(e.message);
    });
});
```